# Hadoop multiple input files error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Im trying to read 2 file from hdfs input with below code but I face with error as follow
I am beginner in mapreduce programing and stuck on this problem for couple of days,any help will be appreciated.

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;

public class Recipe {

public static class TokenizerMapper1
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line=value.toString(); 

        word.set(line.substring(2,8));
        context.write(word,one);
}
}

public static class TokenizerMapper2
extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

String line=value.toString(); 

word.set(line.substring(2,8));
context.write(word,one);
}
}

public static class IntSumReducer
        extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
   String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf,     args).getRemainingArgs();

    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: recipe <in> <out>");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Recipe");

    job.setJarByClass(Recipe.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper1.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper2.class);        
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class,TokenizerMapper1.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class,TokenizerMapper2.class);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
  //FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/in"));
  //FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/out"));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
   // job.submit();
}
```

And i've set program run configuration arguments like this:

/in /put

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>       at Recipe.main(Recipe.java:121)

Comment: You ensure the args are of length 2 here: `if (otherArgs.length != 2)`, yet try to retrieve the third index in the args array here: `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));`. Hence the exception

Comment: You need to input 2 files. You can find an example [here](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/12/joining-two-files-using-multipleinput.html)

Comment: the otherArgs.length is equal 2,then I changed this line:     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
to this:   FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/out"));
but I have error yet:

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues. Program is expecting 3 parameters and you are passing only 2. Also if you have to process multiple input formats you need to use MultipleInputs.

Assume that you invoke program /in1 /in2 /out

```
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, args[0], TokenizerMapper1.class, FirstMapper.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, args[1], TokenizerMapper2.class, SecondMapper.class);
```

You can remove these lines from the code:

```
job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper1.class);
job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper2.class);
```

Comment: 1-I can't understand in directory where I put my input files why I have to have 2 in:    in1,  in2
2-In this case both files have text format and I specify by this line:
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(arg[0]),TextInputFormat.class,
    TokenizerMapper2.class);

3-what you mean about 3 parameters can you explain please
I just copy these code,I don't know what's going on exactly

Answer (score 0):

Now it works with the following modifications:

1. Put every file in a separate directory.
2. Use real address instead of arg[], as shown below:

   ```
   MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/in1"),TextInputFormat.class,TokenizerMapper1.class);
   MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/in2"),TextInputFormat.class,TokenizerMapper1.class);
   FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/out"));
   ```
3. Specify all input and output paths in run configurations\arguments like this:

   ```
   127.0.0.1:9000/in1/DNAIn.txt 127.0.0.1:9000/in2/DNAIn2.txt 127.0.0.1:9000/out
   ```